# How to stop Sublime Text from showing ~ files on the folder menu?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Why is Sublime Text polluting my project view with these files:

`Gruntfile.js~` (not the Gruntfile, but a copy with a tilde at the end).

How can I stop seeing these files in my project view?

Comment: are you also editing those files with emacs, vi, or some other editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences -> Settings - User -> write:

```
{   
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.*~",],
"folder_exclude_patterns": [],
}
```

Or "*.js~" or what you need.